# How can I use XDebug with a PHP upstream behind an nginx reverse proxy?

Tags: php, nginx, docker, xdebug

I have a PHP server running through PHP-FPM which is served with fastcgi through nginx on port `7000`. This application has been dockerized and is running as a running container, e.g. **my_api**.

The `my_api` docker container can be connected to directly via port `7000` (for sanity checking) as well as through another container which acts as an nginx reverse proxy that uses upstreams to expose the `my_api` application (and others) on ports `80` and `443` (port `80` redirects to SSL) through `proxy_pass` directives under the appropriate locations.

If I start an XDebug session using **dbgp** on port `9000` directly against a file served from http://localhost:7000 I can see the debugging session established correctly and I can debug.

However, if I attempt to start the XDebug session against the URL served by the nginx reverse proxy, e.g. https://localhost/my-api, the debug session does not appear to start or at least it doesn't create the connection properly (no breakpoints are hit in my IDE, etc.).

How can I establish an XDebug session for requests made through the nginx reverse proxy?

For purposes of this question, below is a (relevant) sample of my `docker-compose.yml` configuration and `xdebug.ini`:

**docker-compose.yml**:

```
version: "2"

services:
  api:
    build: <path_to_dockerfile>
    ports:
       - 7000:7000
       #- 9000:9000   # may be uncommented for direct debugging access
  nginx_proxy:
    build: <path_to_dockerfile>
    links:
      ...
      - api:api
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
```

**xdebug.ini**

```
zend_extension=xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_enable=true
xdebug.remote_connect_back=1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_autostart=0
```

---

**NB:** I've tried a couple of different configurations to try and get this working, including launching a Docker container running a [dbgpproxy](https://github.com/agroszer/komodo-python-dbgp) but nothing seems to allow me to debug requests which pass through the reverse proxy. It is very possible though that the configuration I was using for these attempts was just wrong.

I have a few theories on what my problems may be, among them the suspicion that it is the reverse proxy's IP address that is being communicated to XDebug via the `remote_connect_back` configuration property.

Any help or insight into how to properly configure XDebug to work with requests that are made to a server via nginx proxy passes to an upstream server would be greatly appreciated!

I can provide further details if it would be helpful!

Comment: `xdebug.remote_connect_back=1` -- make it = `0` and use proper host/IP in `xdebug.remote_host`

Comment: Also -- enable xdebug log and see what it will have to say -- it will show what IP:port it tries to connect and (if debug session is accepted) what is happening there.

Answer (score 3):

Here's how I got PHP Storm to connect to a dockerized php-fpm / nginx application:

Inject the remote host IP into the container. In your host, set the variable:

```
XDEBUG_HOST=$(ipconfig getifaddr en0)
```

I'm not too familiar with docker-compose. I'm using a Kubernetes manifest, but I'm sure there's a way to inject environment variables.

in xdebug.ini:

```
xdebug.remote_host=${XDEBUG_HOST}
```

Now you should be able to set up your xdebug client to listen on `xdebug.remote_port` for debug connections. You'll also have to set up a debug server in PHP Storm or whatever IDE you're using that points to http://127.0.0.1:8080 (or whatever port you're port-forwarding the nginx container to).

Here's what my setup looks like. I'm using PHP Storm but I'm sure you can adapt this to other xdebug clients.

[image: PHP Storm Xdebug server settings]

[image: PHP Storm preferences]

xdebug.ini:

```
zend_extension=xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_port=10000
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
xdebug.idekey=www-data
xdebug.remote_host=${XDEBUG_HOST}
```

Reference: https://shippingdocker.com/xdebug/

Answer (score 1):

Being on windows I needed to disable also the option `remote_connect_back` (on linux it was not needed though)

```
xdebug.remote_connect_back = 0
xdebug.remote_host = host.docker.internal
```

Comment: Yes, this is important as `remote_connect_back` will implicitly override/ignore the `remote_host` setting and try to resolve the IP of the machine running the web request on the app. This is usually helpful, but when using Kubernetes the IP might be unexpected (the one from inside to network, instead of the actual local host IP).

Answer (score 0):

Although it is quite late to answer but I have been trying very hard to implement this idea of `xdebug` i.e. `xdebug` a website behind an `NGINX reverse proxy`. However, I've concluded that there's no way it can be achieved without exposing the website's port, in your case `7000`. I've tried it on `IntelliJ PHPStorm`.

**Reason:**

`xdebug` tries to upload a file `_intellij_phpdebug_validator.php` to the `web` container using `Path Mapping` in order to validate the URL. e.g. it tries to upload the file at `var/www/web`, however, it doesn't find this folder on the `proxy` container since this is the only container accessible using that particular URL `http://web.local/web`. And when it tries to access this file through URL `http://localhost/web/_intellij_phpdebug_validator.php`, the internal proxy pass call tries to access the file `/var/www/web/_intellij_phpdebug_validator.php` and when it doesn't find that file, it returns the error `404 not found`.

In othercase, when I use `xdebug` by exposing my port `8110` and when I access the URL `http://web.local:8110`, it finds the correct Path Mapping i.e. `/var/www/web` and `xdebug` starts working alright.

**NGINX Proxy container Error Log entry** (trying to find the file at `/etc/nginx/html` i.e. the nginx proxy's path whereas it was trying initially to upload the file on `/var/www/web` as per configuration)

```
2021/10/27 10:50:37 [error] 34#34: *25 open() "/etc/nginx/html/_intellij_phpdebug_validator.php" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 172.23.0.1, server: proxy, request: "GET /_intellij_phpdebug_validator.php HTTP/1.1", host: "127.0.0.11"
```

**Website container Error Log entry** (trying to find the file at `/var/www/web` i.e. the website's path whereas it was never uploaded here, thus giving error 404)

```
172.23.0.2 - - [27/Oct/2021:10:51:01 +0000] "GET /web/_intellij_phpdebug_validator.php HTTP/1.0" 404 16 "-" "Java/11.0.6" "172.23.0.1"
```

[image: Graphical Representation of Path Mapping conflict]

[image: Error 404]

[image: After exposing the PORT]